# Graphql Php: Class type definitions vs. schema language

Tags: php, oop, graphql, graphql-php

New to Graphql, using [webonyx/graphql-php](https://github.com/webonyx/graphql-php).

**What benefit is there to defining my schema with class style definitions vs. graphql's provided syntax?**

I have a basic working example using class style schema defs as following:

```
use MyApp\Type\MediaType;
use MyApp\TypeRegistry;

use GraphQL\Type\Definition\ObjectType;
use GraphQL\Type\Definition\Type;

class MusicType extends ObjectType {

    public function __construct() {
        $config = [
            'fields' => [
                'id' => Type::id(),
                'name' => Type::String(),
                'url' => Type::String(),
                'dateStart' => Type::String(),
                'dateEnd' => Type::String()
            ],
            'interfaces' => [
                TypeRegistry::media(),
                TypeRegistry::dateRestricted(),
            ]
        ];
        parent::__construct($config);
    }
}
```

However, I find defining the schema this way to be clunky, with the only real benefit I can see being that I can define my resolvers in the same location as the schema.

Using the schema.graphqls syntax looks cleaner and would be more easily ported to other server-side languages...

```
type Music implements Media {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    url: String!
    dateStart: String
    dateEnd: String
}
```

**What benefit is there to defining my schema with class style definitions vs. graphql's provided syntax?**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the Type language style is more compact and readable. I still have to understand how to write the resolvers for union types and interfaces with this library, anyway, they should be equivalent.